# Is there a way (executor) to use docker-compose within the project.json of a nx project?

Tags: javascript, docker, docker-compose, k6, nomachine-nx

Overall I have little to no idea in how to do this, made some research and didn't find any executor capable of run a docker-compose file which I need to run a K6 test. Any help will be appreciated

I tried using @nx/node but it seems that it's made just to run js scripts.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.